# Match text after last occurrence of a slash including the slash

Tags: javascript, regex

So I need to grab the last part of a url, for example

```
https://www.example.com/no-match/match-this-part/
https://www.example.com/no-match/match-this-part-too
https://www.example.com        <- don't match anything
https://www.example.com/       <- don't match anything
```

I need it to ignore the double slash, and match whatever the last part after the slash is (if the slash can be included would be nice).
The second condition is for the slash to not be the last char (example 1)

This is what I have tried:
`/\/(?:.(?!\/))+$/`

Answer (score 1):

You could use the following regular expression.

```
\bhttps:\/\/[\da-z._~-]+(?:\/[\da-z._~-]+)*(\/[\da-z._~-]+)
```

If there is a match capture group 1 will contain the last forward slash followed by the remainder of the URL, provided at least one character of the URL follows the last forward slash.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/dyHPZb/1/)

Javascript's regex engine performs the following operations.

```
\b               # match a word break
https:\/\/       # match 'http://'
[\da-z._~-]+     # match 1+ chars in char class
(?:              # begin non-cap grp
  \/             # match '/'
  [\da-z._~-]+   # match 1+ chars in char class
)                # end non-cap grp
*                # execute non-cap grp 0+ times
(                # begin cap grp 1
  \/             # match '/' 
  [\da-z._~-]+   # match 1+ chars in char class
)                # end cap grp 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Match the initial part of the URL, then *capture* non-slashes followed by a slash. If there's a match, extract the first capture group:

```js
`https://www.example.com/no-match/match-this-part/
https://www.example.com/no-match/match-this-part-too
https://www.example.com
https://www.example.com/`
  .split('\n')
  .forEach((str) => {
    const match = str.match(/https?:\/\/[^/]+\/.*?([^/]+)\/?$/);
    if (match) {
      console.log(match[1]);
    }
  });
```

`https?:\/\/[^/]+\/.*?([^/]+)\/?$` means:

- `https?:\/\/[^/]+\/`- Match the start of a URL up until the first slash, eg `http://foo.bar/` or `https://foo.bar/`
- `.*?` - Match any character *until* you can:
- `([^/]+)\/?$` - Match and capture non-slashes, possibly followed by a slash, followed by the end of the string

If you want to permit any arbitrary protocol to be matched, use `[^:]+` instead of `https?`.

Comment: but the url doesn't have to start with `https`, it might be `http`, it could be `ftp` too, or some other protocol

Comment: If you want to permit any arbitrary protocol, use `[^:]+` instead, to match non-`:` characters